Can't send multipart request with list of documents
 @override
  Future<SuccessResponse> changeDocument(
    int visaAppointmentId,
    List<NewDocumentsRequest> newDocuments,
    List<int> deletedDocuments,
  ) async {
try {
  FormData data = FormData();
  data.fields
      .add(MapEntry('VisaAppointmentId', visaAppointmentId.toString()));

  for (var element in deletedDocuments) {
    data.fields.add(MapEntry('DeletedDocuments', element.toString()));
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> newDocumentsList = [];
  for (var documentRequest in newDocuments) {
    String fileName = documentRequest.document!.path.split('/').last;

    List<int> bytes = await documentRequest.document!.readAsBytes();

    var contentType = lookupMimeType(documentRequest.document!.path);
    var parts = contentType!.split('/');
    var type = parts[0];
    var subtype = parts[1];
    var mediaType = MediaType(type, subtype);

    MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
      bytes,
      filename: fileName,
      contentType: mediaType,
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> documentMap = {
      'documentType': documentRequest.documentType,
      'document':(MapEntry('document', multipartFile)), 
      'visaApplicantId': documentRequest.visaApplicantId,
    };

    newDocumentsList.add(documentMap);
  }

  String newDocumentsJson = jsonEncode(newDocumentsList);
  data.fields.add(MapEntry('NewDocuments', newDocumentsJson));

  print(formatFormData(data));

  Response response = await refDio.put(
    EndPoints.changeDoc,
    data: data,
  );

  if (response.statusCode != null &&
      response.statusCode! >= 200 &&
      response.statusCode! <= 299) {
    return SuccessResponse.fromJson(response.data);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error ${response.statusCode}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Error: $e');
}

}

That's my request. I use dio package. My data which I send should be like :

 {'VisaAppointmentId': (some id),
    'DeletedDocuments': [] (list of integers),
    'NewDocuments':[ 
    {  'documentType': (some id),
       'visaApplicantId':(some id),
       'document': (my image)
    }]
     }

My error is E/flutter (28624): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'MapEntry<String, MultipartFile>'
I don't know how to send my multipartFile. My document should by sent as bytes.

It seems Dart can't convert MapEntry<String, MultipartFile> to json. Can you try MultipartFile itself like this ? :
   Map<String, dynamic> documentMap = {
  'documentType': documentRequest.documentType,
  'document':multipartFile, 
  'visaApplicantId': documentRequest.visaApplicantId,
   };


In that case It just sends "Instance of Multipart"

In my case i sent multipart file without encoding it. Maybe you should try to send newDocumentsList without encoding.
data.fields.add(MapEntry('NewDocuments', newDocumentsList));
